# Genetic Evolution of Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, evolutionary-algorithm

Ultimately, I am trying to create a genetic algorithm that will evolve a string that matches a target string. I do not have a conventional coding background, so my code will be extremely messy. Here is my complete code.

```
public class Main {

public static double similarity(String s1, String s2) {
    String longer = s1, shorter = s2;
    if (s1.length() < s2.length()) { // longer should always have greater
                                        // length
        longer = s2;
        shorter = s1;
    }
    int longerLength = longer.length();
    if (longerLength == 0) {
        return 1.0;
        /* both strings are zero length */ }
    /*
     * // If you have StringUtils, you can use it to calculate the edit
     * distance: return (longerLength -
     * StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(longer, shorter)) / (double)
     * longerLength;
     */
    return (longerLength - editDistance(longer, shorter)) / (double) longerLength;

}

public static int editDistance(String s1, String s2) {
    s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
    s2 = s2.toLowerCase();

    int[] costs = new int[s2.length() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= s1.length(); i++) {
        int lastValue = i;
        for (int j = 0; j <= s2.length(); j++) {
            if (i == 0)
                costs[j] = j;
            else {
                if (j > 0) {
                    int newValue = costs[j - 1];
                    if (s1.charAt(i - 1) != s2.charAt(j - 1))
                        newValue = Math.min(Math.min(newValue, lastValue), costs[j]) + 1;
                    costs[j - 1] = lastValue;
                    lastValue = newValue;
                }
            }
        }
        if (i > 0)
            costs[s2.length()] = lastValue;
    }
    return costs[s2.length()];
}

public static void printSimilarity(String s, String t) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%.3f is the similarity between \"%s\" and \"%s\"", similarity(s, t), s, t));
}

private static String getCharForNumber(int i) {
    char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ".toCharArray();
    if (i > 27) {
        return null;
    }
    return Character.toString(alphabet[i]);
}

public static String generateString(int numChar) {
    Random random = new Random();
    String randomString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numChar; i++) {
        String temp = getCharForNumber(random.nextInt(27));
        randomString += temp;
    }

    return randomString;
}

public static String returnTwoChildren(String s1, String s2, boolean first) {
    // chromosomes
    // String s1;
    // String s2;

    // crossovers
    String c1;
    String c2;

    Random r = new Random();

    // get a random indices
    int ind1 = r.nextInt(s1.length());

    // make sure ind2 > ind1... leaving this part out;

    // break both strings into parts like in your picture
    String s1part1 = s1.substring(0, ind1);
    String s1part2 = s1.substring(ind1);

    String s2part1 = s2.substring(0, ind1);
    String s2part2 = s2.substring(ind1);

    // combine the parts
    c1 = s1part1 + s2part2;
    c2 = s2part1 + s1part2;
    if (first)
        return c1;
    return c2;
}

Random random;
static String[] population;
static String[] childPopulation;
static String target = "Cat";

public static void createPopulation(int size) {
    population = new String[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        population[i] = generateString(3);

        // System.out.println(population[i]);
        // if (similarity(population[i], target) > 0.3)
        // printSimilarity(population[i], target);
    }
}

public static void fitness(boolean print) {
    for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < population.length; j++) {
            if (similarity(population[j], target) > similarity(population[i], target)) {
                String temp = population[i];
                population[i] = population[j];
                population[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        if (print && similarity(population[i], target) > 0)
            System.out.println(population[i] + ", " + similarity(population[i], target));
    }
}

public static void createChildPopulation(int size) {
    childPopulation = new String[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i += 2) {
        population[i] = returnTwoChildren(population[i], population[i + 1], true);
        population[i + 1] = returnTwoChildren(population[i], population[i + 1], false);
    }

}

public static void mutate() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int prob;
    String sub1, sub2;

    for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < population[i].length(); j++) {
            prob = random.nextInt(100);
            if (prob == 0) {
                sub1 = population[i].substring(0, j);
                sub2 = population[i].substring(j);
                population[i] = sub1 + generateString(1) + sub2;
            }
        }
    }
}

public Main() {
    // fightGame(random);
    //String string1 = "acbdefghijklmnop";
    //String string2 = "1234567891234567";
    int populationSize = 80;
    createPopulation(populationSize);
    boolean print = true;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 800; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            print = true;
            System.out.println("Generation: " + i);
        }
        fitness(print);
        if (similarity(population[0], target) == 1.0) {
            System.out.println("Succeded! Generation: " + i + " String: " + population[0]);
            break;
        }
        createChildPopulation(populationSize);
        mutate();
        print = false;
    }
    // returnTwoChildren(string1, string2);
    System.out.println("Done!");
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}

}
```

When I run the program, it is fine for a few generations then seems to find a problem. I don't know why the strings are getting longer (than three characters). If someone could help point me to the problem, and solution, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: "then seems to find a problem" <-- what problem? Can you give some sample inputs, and the outputs you get vs the expected outputs?

Comment: If I run the app through debug, it seems to go in a loop. What I see in the console just stops around generation 6 or 7. It's supposed to continue going through each generation up to 1000. It has something to do with the substrings, I found.

Answer (score 0):

Problematic is this part:

```
public static void mutate() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int prob;
    String sub1, sub2;

    for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < population[i].length(); j++) {
            prob = random.nextInt(100);
            if (prob == 0) {
                sub1 = population[i].substring(0, j);
                sub2 = population[i].substring(j);
                population[i] = sub1 + generateString(1) + sub2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you hit prob = 0 then your population[i] is mutating, but instead of changing one letter you add one letter.

I think it shold be:

```
sub1 = population[i].substring(0, j-1);
```

instead of

```
sub1 = population[i].substring(0, j);
```

Then your strings will have always 3 letters